# Calling PdfSharp xImg = XImage.FromFile(myImage) immediatly after Bitmap.Save(myImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Tags: image, bitmap, pdfsharp

Good afternoon,
testing a my Window form application I noted an unexpected beaviour when coupling PdfSharp `xImg = XImage.FromFile(myImage)` with a preceding  `Bitmap.Save(myImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg)`.
Briefly:

1. I create a Bitmap from say 195202_000.jpg and then I save it as xxxx.jpg;
2. I create the Ximage.FromFile(xxxx.jpg) and add it to a Pdf in creation;
3. I create another Bitmap this time from 195202_001.jpg and I save it using again the name xxxx.jpg. No problems of overwriting occur.
4. I create the Ximage.FromFile(xxxx.jpg) and add it to the Pdf in creation;
5. I save the Pdf.

Well: at the end, xxxx.jpg contains correctly 195202_001.jpg, the Pdf file contains correctly two pages, but the Issue is that both the two pages contain 195202_000.jpg !!!
I do not understand where this issue raises.
If I change the name of the saved bitmap at every step (say xxxx1.jpg, xxxx2.jpg) all is fine.
Thanks for any help.

Paolo.
I attach the rough code used for producing and analizing the issue.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        
        Dim pdf As New PdfDocument
        Dim fArray(1) As String

        'TWO images.jpg  PathName in array
        fArray(0) = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestInp\195202_000.jpg"
        fArray(1) = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestInp\195202_001.jpg" `

        'Looping the array: creat bitmap from each image in fArray(), draw and save it as a new jpg,
        'immediatly(re - Load) the new jpeg for adding it to a Pdf.
        'Issue that I noted occurs when using the same PathName for saving and re-loading the image.
        'Please see below.
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1

            'CREATE BitmapInp from fArray(i)
            Dim BitmapInp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(fArray(i))

            'DRAW BitmapOut
            Dim BitmapOut As New Bitmap(BitmapInp.Width, BitmapInp.Height)
            Dim grBitmapOut = Graphics.FromImage(BitmapOut)
            grBitmapOut.DrawImage(BitmapInp, 0, 0, BitmapInp.Width, BitmapInp.Height)
            grBitmapOut.Dispose()
            BitmapInp.Dispose()

            'SAVE BitmapOut as "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestOut\xxxx.jpg"
            'NOTE: each time, the Bitmap is saved using the same file name above.
            'overwriting does not raise errors.
            BitmapOut.Save("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestOut\xxxx.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            BitmapOut.Dispose()

                            
            'LOAD BitmapOut as xImg from "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestOut\xxxx.jpg"
            'NOTE: FromFile just saved 
            Using xImg = XImage.FromFile("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestOut\xxxx.jpg")
                Dim page = pdf.AddPage()
                Dim grPdf = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
                page.Width = 500 * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
                page.Height = 500 * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
                xImg.Interpolate = False
                grPdf.DrawImage(xImg, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height)
            End Using

        Next
        'END of loop
        'SAVE Pdf
        pdf.Save("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myTestOut\Dummy.Pdf")

        'Issue: the Pdf contains correctly two pages, but they are equals! And precisely is
        '        the first image that occurs two times!

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the source code of PDFsharp/MigraDoc, but maybe the filename is used as a "unique key" to prevent incorporating multiple copies of the same image into one PDF file.
If the same image is used on multiple pages, only one copy of the image data is included in the file.
I know that PDFsharp tries to prevent multiple copies - and IIRC the filename is the key.

And yes, using different file names should resolve the issue.

Comment: Ohhhhh! Yes! Your answer is absolutely congruent with my Issue. thank you so much :-)